# Changing transform of ParticleSystem makes it not play?

Tags: unity

Unity 2018.2.9f1, only 1 script, there is no other code. The scene is very simple (I just started).

I'm working on a mobile game and I'm trying to play a particle effect at the tap location.

I managed to get the particle effect to play, but when I attempt to change `transform.position` the particle no longer displays at all. I see the TapEffect's GameObject X and Y coordinates being updated in the Editor, but the actual animation is not playing.

This is the script I have attached to my player, the particle is the only child of Player at the moment.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    private ParticleSystem tapEffectParticle;
    private Vector2 touchPos;

    void Start () {
        this.tapEffectParticle = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    void Update () {
        if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                touchPos = touch.position;
                tapEffectParticle.transform.position = touchPos;
                tapEffectParticle.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the `TapEffect` Particle, default particle.

[image]

This is a view of the `Player` GameObject selected.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured your particle system? In particular, the local vs world simulation space setting could be important here. Ensure we have enough information to reproduce your problem in a brand new project, following only the description in your question.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, I updated my question. There is nothing else going on in the scene. I only have 1 sprite that will be my player and a canvas with 1 `Text`. NOTE: I removed the text code from the script (2 lines of code) just to simplify it since it has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working, as DMGregory stated in the comments it had to do with local vs world simulation.

I fixed it this way but in all honesty, I don't understand WHY. Can someone please shed some light as to why we need to do this "Conversion":

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            touchPos = touch.position;
            tapEffectParticle.transform.position = touchPos;
            tapEffectParticle.Play();
        }
    }
```

with this

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            touchPos = touch.position;
            tapEffectParticle.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPos);
            tapEffectParticle.Play();
        }
    }
```